# Click to trigger functions or call a function to bind click event?

Tags: javascript

I have two code like this:

```
myFunc();

function myFunc() {
    var e = document.getElementByClassName("link"),
        i = e.length;
    while (i--) {
        e[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            //do stuff for each a.link
        }, false);
    }
}
```

And

```
function myFunc() {
    //do stuff for each a.link
}

var e = document.getElementByClassName("link"),
    i = e.length;

while (i--) {
    e[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        myFunc()
    }, false);
}
```

With the first one I could use `this` like `var c = this.getAttribute("href")` to get `a.link` attribute.

But second one looks like to have a better performance because it will only call `myFunc()` whenever `a.link` is clicked

So which one is really better for page speed?

**EDIT**
`myFunc` will be used multiple times during ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser vendors strongly recommend web developers to not blindly stare at benchmarks. Vendors optimize the most common ways of doing things. If method A is faster than method B, but method B gains traction, then method B will likely also be fast in the future.

That being said, your first code sample looks weird to me. Just keep it simple. Don't be so eager to trade legibility and maintainability for performance.

---

The first code sample is equivalent to:

```
function clickCallback() {
    console.log(this.href);
}

(function myFunc() {
    var e = document.getElementById("link");
    e.addEventListener("click", clickCallback, false);
}()); // immediate invocation
```

Wrapping it in a function that you execute immediately doesn't do much for you in this case. It's probably slower.

---

The update doesn't change much. There is no reason the first example can't also share the click callback. Depending on how you call the click callback you can preserve the `this` context.

Comment: I'm sorry, my intention was unclear to you, please take a look at edited version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is definitely the correct one for using the event delegation model. It is also marginally better on performance simply because it avoids an extra function call that the first one requires because you are calling `myFunc()` to do the setup instead of just doing the setup as in the second approach.

If you don't have a need to use `myFunc()` elsewhere in the code you can write the handler more simply as:

```
var e = document.getElementById("link");
e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Do all the stuff myFunc does. The 'this' keyword will represent the <a> tag
}, false);
```

Or, you can still declare `myFunc()` separately and save the extra function definition in the handler:

```
function myFunc() {
   // Do stuff. The 'this' keyword will represent the '<a>' tag when 
   // triggered by clicking the <a> tag because it is being called directly 
   // by the handler and has the same scope. It will not represent the
   // <a> tag if you call myFunc() directly somewhere else in the code.
};

var e = document.getElementById("link");
e.addEventListener("click", myFunc, false);
```